# Is there any way to print to stdout, stderr, or log files in google deployment manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I would like to write debug information in my DM templates, but I cannot see nor find a way to generate print statements, logs, or anything to aid in debugging when something goes wrong with my template.

How do I add print or logging to deployment manager?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

I checked, currently the only way to troubleshoot is to rely on the expanded template from the Deployment Manager Dashboard. You can check it in the following URL for a given deployment, but I guess you were already aware of this possibility:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/dm/deployments/details/DEPLOYMENTNAME?project=PROJECTID

However a feature request has been opened and currently the engineering team is working and discussing the best way to provide to the customers this possibility.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/80368273

I advise you to star the feature request in order to get updates via email and to place a comment in order to show the interest of the community. 
All the official communication regarding that feature will be posted there.

> Disclaimer: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support

Comment: Thanks. I was the one that opened the FR.